# Bus notation in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I always thought that bus notations is annotated like this:

```
input bus[MSB:LSB]
```

where MSB >= LSB.

But recently, I was told that even this is possible:

```
wire LSB >= MSB.
```

Is it even true?

If so, then how come synthesizer tools get the bus size and all? Do they consider that whichever index is big is MSB?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, both directions of bit numbering could be used in declarations. However, the same ordering must be used when you do bit selection. For example

```
wire [0:15] bus;
reg  [15:0] data;
assign bus [3:6] = data[3:0];
```

In most cases through industry the second notation is used (msb > lsb) and it is encouraged for consistency reasons. However in some situations it is convenient to do the opposite.

Comment: This is not correct. Maybe this was a typo. You need to select `bus[6:3]`

Comment: it **is** correct. Because the `bus`  was declared as `[0:15]` bit select must be `[3:6]`, not vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 3):

The bit numbering does not matter until you select a single bit or part select of the bus. As long as you know how the signal is declared any tool can figure out the bit width and msb ordering